# Google Calendar API returns null in colorId

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have developed a script using the Google Calendar API for PHP that recovers the event data of a managed business account with GSUITE, it recovers practically all the data except the colorID and the creator-> displayName that delivers them in null.

I tested this same script with my personal gmail account and it recovers me absolutely everything.

What should I consider in this case?

Comment: Hi Andres! You may want to consider translating this to english if you speak it, this website is primarily english and you're far more likely to get help if your question is in a language most people here speak :)

Comment: thaks for your suggestion, I did it!..

Answer (score 1):

This is the [intended behavior](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-calendar-api/r17_Q3kpvVM/_VsGUYPENJ4J). If you perform this API call on the events that you yourself have created, it will return the colorId and your creator. But if you didn't create the event, you wont have access to these properties.

Here's a sample response from my own event:

```
{
 "colorId": "5",
 "creator": {
  "email": "bruceWayne@marvelstudios.com",
  "self": true
 }
```

Additional Note:

The [creator.displayName](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) isn't always available.

> The creator's name, if available.

Comment: thanks noogui, but i have created calendars, events and they are shared with email account generated inseide the service account file (json). but there is some that I can't understand because I tested the same script with my personal gmail and all data is retrived. but with gsuite I've lost only colorID and displayName of creator...